# Multiple conditional expressions and ": expected" error

Tags: c#, validation, if-statement, textbox

```
bool validateTextBox =
    Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(merk_textBox, "Voer een merk in") ?
    Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(serienummer_textBox, "Voer een serie nummer in") ? 
    Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(h_nummer_textBox, "Voer een h nummer in") ?
    Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(locatie_textBox, "Voer een locatie in") ?
    Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(status_textBox, "Voer een status in") ?
    Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(in_bezit_van_textBox, "Voer een naam in") ?
    Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(serienummer_textBox, "Voer een laptop nummer in") ?
    Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(olc_nummer_textBox, "Voer een olc nummer in")
    : false;
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Syntax error, ':' expected
```

At the end of the line. Why is that?

Comment: It will be easier if you don't use the ternary form o `IF`.

Comment: Do you expect a return value of true when all of the conditions are true or when one or more of the conditions are true? I assume all conditions are required to be true but as can be seen from the answers this is not clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `&&`. You don't need [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) here

```
bool validateTextBox = 
    Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(merk_textBox, "Voer een merk in") 
    && Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(serienummer_textBox, "Voer een serie nummer in") 
    && Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(h_nummer_textBox, "Voer een h nummer in") 
    && Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(locatie_textBox, "Voer een locatie in") 
    && Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(status_textBox, "Voer een status in") 
    && Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(in_bezit_van_textBox, "Voer een naam in") 
    && Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(serienummer_textBox, "Voer een laptop nummer in") 
    && Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(olc_nummer_textBox, "Voer een olc nummer in") ;
```

Correct Syntax of [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
 condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

Answer (score 2):

With a [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) you'll need a matching ":" for every "?"

More like this:

```
bool validateTextBox =
    Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(merk_textBox, "Voer een merk in") ?
    Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(serienummer_textBox, "Voer een serie nummer in") ? 
    Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(h_nummer_textBox, "Voer een h nummer in") ?
    Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(locatie_textBox, "Voer een locatie in") ?
    Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(status_textBox, "Voer een status in") ?
    Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(in_bezit_van_textBox, "Voer een naam in") ?
    Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(serienummer_textBox, "Voer een laptop nummer in") ?
    Security.IsValidateTextBoxSuccess(olc_nummer_textBox, "Voer een olc nummer in")
    : false : false : false : false : false : false : false;
```

Comment: Yikes. Why not simply `&&`?

Comment: Just showing why the OPs code won't compile, there are other ways like you said but that wasn't the question :)